# Not able to access json object in Backbone View Handlebars

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, browserify

Backbone View:

```
        var $ = require('jquery'),
        Handlebars = require('handlebars'),
        Backbone = require('backbone'),
        channel = require('../../templates/dashboard/channelstats.html'),
        channelstatsCollection = require('../../collections/dashboard/ChannelStatsCollection'),
        mainJs = require('../../libs/main');
var ChannelStatsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#divstatsview",
    initialize: function () {

        this.collection = new channelstatsCollection();

        var api_token = mainJs.get_api_token();

        this.collection.fetch(
                {
                    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + api_token.access_token},
                    success: function (collection, response, options) {

                        var tpl = channel;

                        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
$(this.el).html(tpl({orders:JSON.stringify(response)}));                         
                    }
                }
        );



    }

});
// Our module now returns our view
module.exports = ChannelStatsView;
```

Handlebars template:

```
   {{#orders.records}}

    {{#by_status}}

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 new-item centered white-panel">



        <h2 class="white-header">    {{PROCESSING}}</h2>

        <!--                  <div class="text-danger"><i class="fa fa-bell fa-3x"></i></div>-->
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div>      <b>{{PROCESSING}} new </b>Orders</div>
        <div>   <b>{{SHIPPED}} </b3>Pending</div>


        <br/>
        <div><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-2x"></i></div>
        <a href="#" id="btnsync">Sync</a>


    </div>

    {{/by_status}}
    {{/orders.records}}
```

My JSON:

```
 {
   "metadata":{
      "recordcount":1
   },
   "records":[
      {
         "count":0,
         "by_status":[
            {
               "OUTOFSTOCK":0
            },
            {
               "PROCESSING":19,
               "by_channel":[
                  {
                     "Some":1
                  },
                  {
                     "Some1":18
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "RECEIVED":0
            },
            {
               "SHIPPED":26,
               "by_channel":[
                  {
                     "Demo":26
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I get a blank page and nothing shows up.

**NOTE:**

I am using hbsfy to compile my templates for me so `tpl` is a compiled template and not an html file.

**EDIT:**

My json object

[image]

Comment: Are you compiling the Handlebars template? Are you using browserify (or some other packaging tool) to package your js? If you are then you can use the hbsfy transform to precompile your templates. You also have some errors in your template. It looks like you are trying to loop through the records array, you will need to use the built-in each helper {{#each records }}{{/each}}.

Comment: Please check my note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use built-in each helper to iterate over the records and by_status arrays.

```
{{#each orders.records}}
  {{#each by_status}}
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 new-item centered white-panel">
      <h2 class="white-header">{{PROCESSING}}</h2>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <div><b>{{PROCESSING}} new </b>Orders</div>
      <div><b>{{SHIPPED}} </b>Pending</div>
      <br/>
      <div><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-2x"></i></div>
      <a href="#" id="btnsync">Sync</a>
    </div>
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

I am not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish, but the code above will output 4 divs. It will output 1 div for each element in the by_status array. It seems like you are just trying to output 1 div with a summary. If that is the case, you would probably need to do something like below.

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 new-item centered white-panel">
  <h2 class="white-header">{{orders.records.0.by_status.1.PROCESSING}}</h2>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div><b>{{orders.records.0.by_status.1.PROCESSING}} new </b>Orders</div>
  <div><b>{{orders.records.0.by_status.3.SHIPPED}} </b>Pending</div>
  <br/>
  <div><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-2x"></i></div>
  <a href="#" id="btnsync">Sync</a>
</div>
```

The code above assumes that the PROCESSING and SHIPPED elements always exist in the same place in the by_status array. This is probably not very wise. My recommendation would be to change the structure of your JSON response, or if that is not possible do some processing in your Backbone view before passing it to the template.

**EDIT:** Worked when i made my code to the following below

```
 <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 new-item centered white-panel">
  <h2 class="white-header">{{orders.records.0.by_status.1.PROCESSING}}</h2>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div><b>{{orders.0.records.0.by_status.1.PROCESSING}} new </b>Orders</div>
  <div><b>{{orders.0.records.0.by_status.3.SHIPPED}} </b>Pending</div>
  <br/>
  <div><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-2x"></i></div>
  <a href="#" id="btnsync">Sync</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi i try to show {{orders.metadata.recordcount}} that doesn't show up for me either.

Comment: Hey it worked thanks though i need to add orders.0.records.0.by_status.1.PROCESSING